# Ordem das tabelas faz diferença na modelagem?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou construindo um banco de dados com as seguintes tabelas:

```
Aluno: id_aluno, aluno_login, aluno_senha, aluno_nome, aluno_sobrenome, aluno_cidade

Aluno_Categoria: id_categoria_curso, id_categoria, id_aluno

Categoria (ou curso): id_categoria, categoria_nome, categoria_curso
```

Um `curso` possui uma `categoria` ou uma `categoria` possui um `curso`? Se eu inverter a ordem tem algo a ver ou caímos naquela questão "a ordem dos fatores não altera o produto"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por que não ambos? Por isso que o banco de dados é relacional, você faz composição como quiser. Por isso ele é superior a outros modelos na maioria dos casos. Relacionamento não envolve propriedade e sim ligação.

Eu não posso dizer se o modelo está certo porque depende sempre de coleta bem feita de requisitos. E a pergunta também não está lá muito bem escrita, mas o relacionamento é isto.

Comment: Me expressei errado Maniero, então você conclui que diante dessa situação não haverá mudança alguma, não importando a ordem que eu colocar.   Sobre a pergunta tendo a escrita errada, o que recomenda para não receber votos negativos?

Comment: Não existe ordem alguma, existem relações, são coisas distintas. Nunca ouvi falar em ordem no modelo relacional. Poderia detalhar mais a pergunta, colocar o que está fazendo de fato. A descrição não bate com as tabelas mostradas., não mostra relação alguma.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, 
entendo que você deva avaliar: 
1- Posso ter várias categorias de curso? 
Ex.: 1.a)categoria Banco de Dados-: cursos relacionados: Administração de BD, programação em BD, BD NoSQL, etc
1.b)categoria Engenharia de Software-: cursos relacionados: Levantamento e Análise de requisitos, Padrões de Dev, etc

2 - As categorias no curso não seriam melhor interpretadas como módulos?
Ex.: 2.a) Curso Banco de dados: módulos relacionados: Instalando o SGBD e configurando o ambiente, Criando o BD, Administrando o BD, etc.
2.b) Curso Programação OO: módulos relacionados: Conceitos, Prog. Estruturada, Princípios de OO, Os pilares de OO, etc.

Ao meu ver a ordem de relacionamento neste caso influi no resultado final, porém é necessário você avaliar qual a necessidade da sua modelagem.

Comment: Sim, acabei de organizar minhas tabelas e possuem curso>categoria>modulo. Obrigado pela ajuda.